# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_the_post_thumbnail_id() on FB meta data plugin developing

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried to  get Thumbnail ID with this code:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_the_post_thumbnail_id(),'full')
```

i want to get thumbnail id on a post, but when i insert a thumbnail image then it show the error but if not insert an thumbnail image then it works fine.
please help me

Comment: There isn't `get_the_post_thumbnail_id` function in the wordpress core. that's why you're getting error. where you're using the code provided? and what is your goal?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan i am new in wp plugin development and i try to make a FB meta data insert plugin by watching videos, <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_the_post_thumbnail_id(),'full');
            ?>
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image[0] ?>"/> ?>
I'm getting an error when i set featured picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post featured image url get function `get_the_post_thumbnail_url(post->ID)`

```
get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID,'full');
```